# Pregmatch last instance of a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to know how I can match the word/s after the last instance of `by`. For example below I have a list of `$books`. The book is in the format `<book title> by <author>` The book title can contain any character/s or nothing at all. However, the author can only be letters, numbers and underscores. I want to echo out the authors only.

I managed to do this with a combination of `explode()`, `rtrim()` and `end()` but how would I do this using preg_match / regex.

```
<pre><?php

$books = ['Big Blue Book by Steven', 'Dance by her by Mike', 'One day by by by', 'Hiphop Party by DJ340_Cool', ' by Paul12', 'by jasonB'];

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $temp = explode("by ", $book);
    $temp = rtrim(end($temp));
    echo("$temp\n");
}
```

The result I want:

```
Steven
Mike
by
DJ340_Cool
Paul12
jasonB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this code:

```sh
foreach ($books as $book) {
   if (preg_match('/^(?:.*\h)?by\h+(\S+)/', $book, $m))
      echo $m[1] . "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Steven
Mike
by
DJ340_Cool
Paul12
jasonB
```

Here regex `(?:^.*\h)?by\h+(\S+)` matches last `by` surrounded with 1+ whitespaces on both sides due to use of greedy `.*` before. We capture 1+ non-whitespaces in 1st capture group and print it in `if` condition.

Comment: This answer is not matching the `"by jasonB"` case. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I made an assumption that sentence doesn't start with word `by` but making an edit to address this.